# How do I run my C++ application in Netbeans with terminal arguments?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I want to run my C++ application in Netbeans with 2 terminal arguments. I tried looking under Project Properties > Run, but I only get the following screen.

[image]

I tried tinkering with all of the fields, but none of them altered terminal arguments. How do I specify terminal arguments?

Comment: @JesseGood I'm very sure this is the solution. I think you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put them after the `"${OUTPUT_PATH}"` in `Run Command`. For example, if you wanted to pass `1` as an argument, this is what it should look like: `"${OUTPUT_PATH}" 1`